# How to serialize the absolute minimum amount of data in a Serializable implementation?

Tags: java, serialization, objectoutputstream, objectinputstream

I'm new to `Java.io.Serializable`, so my apologies if this is a completely newb question. What I'd like to do is implement `readObject()` and `writeObject()` such that the absolute minimum of data is serialized. I'd basically like to only write a few primitives and no information about object identity and no information about the Object graph, as in my application I'll know all that information at the time I deserialize this object.
I hope this makes sense! I do apologize for the high-level nature of the question as I'm quite new at this and may not have the correct vocabulary here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `transient` word for declaring fields so they won't be serialized.
Then you won't have to implement read/writeObject youself - it will serialize only what you want to be serialized.

More on this here: http://www.javabeat.net/examples/2009/02/18/what-is-transient-keyword-in-java/

Comment: Eugene, thanks for your answer. I haven't had a chance to review it just yet but will take a look tonight and see if this resolves the problem.